# Airflow unable to execute all the dependent tasks in one go from UI

Tags: python, airflow

My DAG has 3 tasks and we are using Celery executor as we have to trigger individual tasks from UI.We are able to execute the individual task from UI.

The problem which we are facing currently, is that we are unable to execute all the steps of DAG from UI in one go, although we have set the task dependencies.

We are able to execute the complete DAG from command line but is there any way to execute the same via UI ?

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you just need to restart the *webserver* and the *scheduler*? It happens when you change your code, like adding new tasks.
Please post more details and some code.